# Still confused about the grid in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi I'm a beginner trying to create my own web layouts in Photoshop that are based on the Bootstrap 3 grid.

I've downloaded a few .psd files that mimic the Bootstrap 3 grid so you can based your designs around them.

I've also created an html grid using Bootstrap that you can see here http://juanchandler.com/grid-test.html view source to see the code.

My question is why the columns aren't 70 pixels wide and a gutter width of 30 pixels as is the case with the .psd grids...I've taken a screenshot of the .psd grid with my html over the top so you can see how the columns don't line up. http://juanchandler.com/screenshot3.jpg ie. the red / salmon columns are supposed the gutters but my html columns fall over them.

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap's grid is based on percentages, so each column will be a percentage and not a precise pixel width. The only time it's 70px on a single col-*-1 column is when the screen size is equal to or greater than 1170px IF you are using a .container (and not the .container-fluid). The gutter is the padding inside the columns, so you don't see that because there's no inner div wrapping the content, in order to see the gutters, you have to have div or some kind of container inside the column:

```
<div class="col-sm-1 cell4"><div class="inner">&nbsp;</div></div>
```

And color that inside div, not the col-*-*

### See example: http://jsbin.com/qotos/1/edit

[image]

As far as using Photoshop, since 2011 I've been doing responsive design and haven't used it. What I do is design in CSS and take a screen shot. Learn to use LESS or SCSS. Learn CSS first though.